# Table per Concrete Type Mapping Issue in EF Code First 4.2

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm getting a `EntityType 'User' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType` error.

Model:

```
public abstract class KeyedEntityBase
{
    public int ID { get; private set; }
}

public class User : KeyedEntityBase
{
    public string UserName { get; private set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; private set; }
}
```

Context:

```
public class LSBPortalContext : DbContext
{
    public LSBPortalContext()
        : base("LSBPortalDB")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("User");
        });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try configuring the PK with `modelBuilder.Entity<KeyedEntityBase>().HasKey(k => k.Id)`?

Comment: When doing that I get 'The key component 'ID' is not a declared property on type 'User'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid primitive property.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues was that I didn't actually map the KeyedEntityBase class. Once I did that it all worked properly.